# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named "calculations"

Tags: python, databricks

I have made a project tree:

```
.
├── calculations
│   ├── calculation1.py
│   └── calculation2.py
|   └── __init__.py
├── final_combinations
│   ├── project.py
│   └── non_project.py
```

In `project.py` I import the calculations from calculations folder:

```
from calculations.calculation1 import calculation1
from calculations.calculation2 import calculation2

def project():
    x = calculation1(13) + calculation2(15)
    return x
```

This works on my PC well, but when my colleague run this codes after pulling from my repo it gives error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "calculations"` . In his computer he has added python to his PATH. We use Visual Studio Code and have same settings. File is uploaded to Databricks and run on it using VSCode plug-in databricks-connect.

Comment: you don't have any module named `calculation` in your code. You have `calculation1` and `calculation2`. Where does `calculation` come from?

Comment: sorry I meant "calculation"

Comment: it is defined in the tree as the folder name. folder name is ``` calculations``` . i've added an __init__.py file to it. this has run fine until it was run on another computer.

Comment: could you please show us where in the tree you have defined `calculation`? I cannot see it. You import calculations but somehow your code gives an error that the module calculation is not found. Where is calculation defined?

Comment: it's the folder that contains the __init__.py file. the folder's name is calculations. I'm trying to import files from this folder

Comment: Have you noticed that `calculation`  is not the same as `calculations` right? The error that you post refers to `calculation` which is not defined anywhere, you just have a folder named `calculations` which inside has the files `calculation1` and `calculation2`

Comment: sorry in my code snippet it did says "calculations" and it still didn't work. I don't think syntax is problem here.

Comment: Is the code deployed into workspace or in repos?

Comment: @AlexOtt in workspace

Answer (score 0):

This is a "known" behavior when workspace files are used.  By default, only the current folder of the file is added to the `sys.path`, so if you have a subdirectory, you can do `import subdir.module`. But in your case you have a module a level above, so you need to append that folder to the `sys.path` to be discoverable - it's covered in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/workspace-modules.html).

Alternatively, you can use [Repos](https://docs.databricks.com/en/repos/index.html) that have a bit different behavior - the `sys.path` is populated not only with the current directory, but also with the root of the repository.